# Ответ от страницы всегда 200, однако данные для авторизации не верны

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Так же при попытке получить код основной страницы сайта, сохраняется лишь код страницы авторизации. Возможно где-то сохранены данные для авторизации и при изменение кода программы они почему-то не изменяются.

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent().random

session = requests.Session()

headers = {
    "user-agent": ua
}

log_link = "http://web-iais.admin.tstu.ru:7777/zion/wwv_flow.accept"

url = "http://web-iais.admin.tstu.ru:7777/zion/f?p="503:41:*******35::NO::P41_GROUP_ID:****"

ses_data = {
    "p_flow_id": "****",
    "p_flow_step_id": "****",
    "p_instance": "лишние_данные_***48835",
    "p_page_submission_id": "******20",
    "p_request": "LOGIN",
    "p_arg_names": [
        "*******809",
        "3759284628130970814",
        "*******53508",
        "************60"],
    "p_t01": "***********",
    "p_t02": "************",
    "p_t03": "",
    "p_arg_checksums": [
        "3754****************4CAB13****0**C10",
        "3754*********************A3**10"],
    "p_t04": "",
    "p_md5_checksum": "",
    "p_page_checksum": "E************5E1BA02"
}

prof_resp = session.get(url, data=ses_data, headers=headers)
print(prof_resp.status_code)

with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(prof_resp.text)
```

Comment: Нужен `post` запрос, для входа, а не `get`.

Comment: @СергейКох, тогда почему в таком случае ответ 200? Даже при изменении кода на такой:
response = session.post(log_link, data=ses_data, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
mpage = session.get(url, data=ses_data, headers=headers)
print(mpage.status_code)
print(mpage.text)
Я получаю в ответ 200 и код страницы авторизации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный сайт использует защиту от парсеров. Чтобы ее преодолеть проще использовать selenium.